# Price Calculation based off user input React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, math, calculation

I have a function that calculates a price based off of square footage and a base price.

The price goes up 10% for every 500sqft after 2000sqft. Anything 2000sqft and below is 149.99.

The function is below...

```
checkPrice = () => {
   debugger;
   let base_price = 149.99;
      if(this.state.propertySqft > 2000){
   let overage = this.state.propertySqft - 2000;
   let percentage = Math.floor(overage % 500) * 10;
   base_price += base_price * percentage;
   this.setState({ totalPrice: base_price });

  }
}
```

the issue I am having, is the `percentage` comes up as '0' if the square footage is a round number, and the `math.ceil(overage % 500)` seems to not be working properly.

for example.... if i was to put in 5001 sqft, the price should be 149.99 * 60% which would be 239.98, but it comes up as 164.98 as the `percentage` only ends up being 10, instead of 60.

If i put in 5000 sqft, the `percentage` comes up as '0', which this is the case for any round number I enter as the square footage.

Does anyone have any idea what Im doing wrong here or why this is not working the way Im expecting it to?

Comment: I guess you want `Math.floor(overage / 500)` ...

Comment: Also your percentage is in percent, you want to turn it into [0, 1] by dividing it with 100. Then add 1, and multiply the price with that.

Comment: I tried that as well! Sorry I should have clarified that I tried that already. It gives me the same issue which is why Im so confused lol. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: 3000 % 500 is 0 ... your debugger should tell you that ...

Comment: It does tell me its 0 but I just wasnt sure why it was 0, i was under the impression that it would be 6. Also I didnt try to turn it into [0, 1] by dividing it with 100. Then add 1.. maybe thats my issue? Ill try that now.

Comment: Ah, you don't have to add 1, as you *increase* the base price by 10%. But currently, you increase the price by 1.000%.

Comment: switched the % to a / like you suggested, as I actually didnt try using a "/" instead of a "%" and divided the percentage by 100 and its working properly now. Thank you so very much for your help Jonas!!

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator is used to get the *distance* to the next lower multiple, e.g. `2006 % 500` would be `6`, as `500 * 4 + 6 = 2006`. You want to *divide*, to get 4 in this case: `2006 / 500 = 4.00...`, then floor it to the next integer.

Also if you multiply the base price with 10, you don't increase it by 10%, rather by 1000%. You probably want 0.1 (*10 per hundred*).

I'd write it as:

```
 const basePrice = 149.99;

 const checkPrice = () => {
  this.setState(({ propertySqft }) => { // asynchronous access to this.state is dangerous, use a callback!     
    const percentage = Math.max(
      0, // ensure that it only gets more 
      Math.floor((propertySqft - 2000) / 500) * (10 / 100)
    );

    return { totalPrice: basePrice * (1 + percentage),  };
  });
};
```